# Prevent out-of-order execution in java

Tags: java, execution, volatile

Essentially I have the following two statements:

```
Project project = projectDao.createProject(...);
projectDao.deleteInProgressEntry(...);
```

I want to make sure that the project creation is completed finished *before* the inProgress entry is deleted (before the next line is executed). The statements are completely independent of each other, so I am worried that the compiler may not respect the ordering in the code.

I have done some reading about volatile, and I tried adding volatile to the beginning of the first line so I would have `volatile Project project`. But that doesn't compile. I have had trouble finding what I am looking for without getting lost in multithreading, atomic operations, etc.

Comment: Have you got multiple `Thread`s? If not ignore everything you have read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The statements are completely independent of each other, so I am worried that the compiler may not respect the ordering in the code.

No, it will. It's possible that *other threads* may observe the results of the operations out of order - but from the perspective of the executing thread, it will definitely execute in order.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you. So I swear I've learned that compilers can re-order the flow of execution to optimize. Is that only true of lower lever languages or just not true at all?

Comment: @jlars62: Well you only asked about Java. I wouldn't try to apply any rules of thumb - just check for each language you're using. Note that even within Java, I've simplified things a bit... the *effect* must be the same as if it were executing in order, but the JIT could still reorder things in a way which doesn't matter. You don't need to worry, because it really won't be observable.